# How can I dynamically generate a python symbol statement?

Tags: python, sympy

I am trying to write a routine that normalizes (rewrites) a mathematical equation that may have more than one symbol on the `LHS` so that it only has one.

The following code illustrates what I want to do

Assume I have an equation

```
ln(x)-ln(x1)= -(a+by)
```

I want to solve for x or return

```
x=x1*exp(-a+by)
```

Using `sympy` I can do the following

```py
from sympy import *

formula=' log(x)-log(x1) =-(a+b*y)'
lhs,rhs=formula.split('=',1)
x,x_1,y,a,b,y=symbols('x x_1 y a b y')    
r=sympy.solve(eval(lhs)-eval(rhs),x)
r

==> 
Output: [x1*exp(-a - b*y)]
```

I am trying to automate this for a range of input lines as follows

```
from sympy import *
import re

# eventually to be read ina loop from a file
formula="DLOG(SAUMMCREDBISCN/SAUNECONPRVTXN) =-0.142368233181-0.22796245228*(LOG(SAUMMCREDBISCN(-1)/SAUNECONPRVTXN(-1))+0.2*((SAUMMLOANINTRCN(-1)-SAUINTR(-1))/100)-LOG(SAUNYGDPMKTPKN(-1)))+0.576050997065*SAUNYGDPGAP_/100"

#try to convert formula into a string containing just the synbols
sym1=formula.replace("*"," ")
sym1=sym1.replace("DLOG"," ")
sym1=sym1.replace("LOG"," ")
sym1=sym1.replace("EXP"," ")
sym1=sym1.replace("RECODE"," ")


sym1=re.sub('[()/+-\=]',' ',sym1)
sym1=re.sub(' +',' ',sym1)
#This logic works for this particular formula
sym1

#now generate a string that has, instead of spaces between symbols
ss2=sym1.replace(' ',',')

#This is the part that does not work I want to generate a command that effectively says
#symbol,symbol2,..,symboln=symbols('symbol1 symbol2 ... symboln')

#tried this but it fails
eval(ss2)=symbols(sym1)
```

Generates the result

```
    eval(ss2)=symbols(sym1)
                           ^
SyntaxError: can't assign to function call
```

Any help for this `py` noob, would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Did you mean to check for equality (i.e. `==`), or `eval(ss2) == symbols(sym1)`?

Comment: Do you know about lists and dicts?

Comment: No I am trying to create a command that would have the form x,a,b=symbol('x a b') where I am dynamically generating the z,a,b and 'x a b' lements of the command by parsing the input string.

Comment: @blorgbeard No, I don't -- I am a  noob. But a quick look at the doc makes me understand why can see why you ask, will investigate further.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A colleague of mine (Ib Hansen) gave me a very nice and elegant solution to the original problem (how to solve for the complicated expression) that by-passed the string manipulation solution that my original question was struggling with and which most answers addressed.

His solution is to use **sympify** and **solve** from sympy

```
from sympy import sympify, solve
import re

def normalize(var,eq,simplify=False,manual=False):  
    '''normalize an equation with respect to var using sympy'''
    lhs, rhs = eq.split('=')
    kat = sympify(f'Eq({lhs},{rhs})')
    var_sym = sympify(var)
    out = str(solve(kat, var_sym,simplify=simplify,manual=manual))[1:-1] 
    return f'{var} = {out}'
```

This works perfectly

````
from sympy import sympify, solve
import re

def norm(var,eq,simplify=False,manual=False):  
    '''normalize an equation with respect to var using sympy'''
    lhs, rhs = eq.split('=')
    kat = sympify(f'Eq({lhs},{rhs})')
    var_sym = sympify(var)
    out = str(solve(kat, var_sym,simplify=simplify,manual=manual))[1:-1] # simplify takes for ever
    return f'{var} = {out}'

``` Re write equation spelling out the dlog (delta log) function that python does no know, and putting log into lowe case '''

test8=norm('saummcredbiscn','log(saummcredbiscn/sauneconprvtxn) -log(saummcredbiscn(-1)/sauneconprvtxn(-1)) =-0.142368233181-0.22796245228*(log(saummcredbiscn(-1)/sauneconprvtxn(-1))+0.2*((saummloanintrcn(-1)-sauintr(-1))/100)-log(saunygdpmktpkn(-1)))+0.576050997065*saunygdpgap_/100')
print (test8)
````

with result

```
saummcredbiscn = 0.867301828366361*sauneconprvtxn*(saummcredbiscn(-1.0)/sauneconprvtxn(-1.0))**(19300938693/25000000000)*saunygdpmktpkn(-1.0)**(5699061307/25000000000)*exp(0.00576050997065*saunygdpgap_ + 0.00045592490456*sauintr(-1.0) - 0.00045592490456*saummloanintrcn(-1.0)
```

Answer (score 3):

`var('a b c')` will inject symbol name 'a', 'b', 'c' into the namespace but perhaps @Blorgbeard is asking about lists or dicts because instead of creating many symbols you could put the symbols in a dictionary and then access them by name:

```
>>> formula=' log(x)-log(x1) =-(a+b*y)'
>>> eq = Eq(*map(S, formula.split('=', 1)))
>>> v = dict([(i.name, i) for i in eq.free_symbols]); v
{'y': y, 'b': b, 'x': x, 'x1': x1, 'a': a}
>>> solve(eq, v['x'])
[x1*exp(-a - b*y)]
```

So it is not actually necessary to use `eval` or to have a variable matching a symbol name: `S` can convert a string to an expression and `free_symbols` can identify which symbols are present. Putting them in a dictionary with keys being the Symbol name allows them to be retrieved from the dictionary with a string.

Comment: This was exasctly what I was looking for.  Many thanks. Uovioted and marked as answer.

Answer (score 0):

I think what you want to generate a string from these two statements and then you can eval that string

```
str_eq = f'{ss2} = {symbols(sym1)}'
print(str_eq)
>>' ,SAUMMCREDBISCN,SAUNECONPRVTXN,SAUMMCREDBISCN,SAUNECONPRVTXN,SAUMMLOANINTRCN,SAUINTR,SAUNYGDPMKTPKN,SAUNYGDPGAP_, = (SAUMMCREDBISCN, SAUNECONPRVTXN, SAUMMCREDBISCN, SAUNECONPRVTXN, SAUMMLOANINTRCN, SAUINTR, SAUNYGDPMKTPKN, SAUNYGDPGAP_)'
```

The first line says - give me a string but run the python code between the `{}` before returning it.  For instance

```
print(f'Adding two numbers: (2+3) = {2 + 3}')

>> Adding two numbers: (2+3) = 5
```

Answer (score 0):

First, maybe this could help make your code a bit denser.

If I understand correctly, you're trying to assign a variable using a list of names. You could use `vars()[x]=`:

```
import re
from sympy import symbols

symbol_names = re.findall("SAU[A-Z_]+",formula)
symbol_objs = symbols(symbol_names)

for sym_name,sym_obj in zip(symbol_names,symbol_objs):
    vars()[sym] = sym_obj
```